# Installing module in python with anaconda and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, module, anaconda, jupyter

I've been having a problem with installing modules, and I can't find an exact solution to it anywhere. What I'm trying to do is use anaconda to install a module. When I type into the anaconda command prompt:

```
pip install imbox
```

it says it installs. So then i open jupyter notebook by simply using

```
jupyter notebook
```

Everything seems ok until I try to

```
from imbox import Imbox
```

and I get

```
No module named imbox
```

How would I make jupyter notebook include that module?

Comment: have you tried using conda to install the module instead? conda install imbox? Could be that pip is installing to your base python site-packages, but jupyter is using a different python kernel.

Comment: I did, but conda doesn't include imbox.

Comment: Where does pip say it is installing the package? Does it match the location of your conda installation?

Comment: Well since I already installed it at some point before i restarted it, so all it says is:  
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): imbox in c:\python27\l
ib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python27\lib
\site-packages (from imbox)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.

Comment: How would I change the location from  c:\python27\l ib\site-packages  to  C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 6):

Try using the pip that comes with conda, instead of your default pip.

`PATH_TO_CONDA_DIR/bin/pip install imbox`

In your case:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda2\bin\pip install imbox`

Alternative, install the package again, in the specified location:

`pip install --target=C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages imbox`

Comment: That just outputted:  
    The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: You may have to add .exe after pip, on windows.

Comment: Also, I put USERNAME in there, not your actual username.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, but I'd also like to know if I could change the default path, so that I could use the simple "pip install" and it would install to the correct area.

Comment: That's a modification to your PATH. Just add the conda directory to your windows PATH.

Comment: And how exactly would I do that? Sorry, I'm still new to some technical things like this.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows#9546462

Comment: That site is confusing, with many methods on how to do it, which one are you telling me to use? Please be more specific.

Comment: Actually, all I did was delete the folder that it was defaulting to. That worked perfectly, so thanks for the help!